# Are these kittens boys are girls ? Need to know asap (sorry for bad pics they won’t stay still)

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

[image]
I’m [image]
[image]

Sorry for bad pictures they wouldn’t stay still, need help
ASAP. Thought it was a boy and girl but I think I’m wrong and I don’t want to give them away not knowing for sure

Comment: #1: girl. #2,3: no-idea